# Search console server error for feed

Tags: web-crawler, feed

I am getting "Server error" in "Search Console - Yoast SEO" tab. How can I solve this problem? e.g. /category/blog/hair-loss-treatment/feed/

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer- Thanks. can you help me?